pnpm monorepo error with peer dependencies "Rollup failed to resolve import"
I have a monorepo project using turborepo. I was using yarn version 4 and everything was working perfectly fine but then I had the brilliant idea of changing from yarn to pnpm since it was recommended for monorepo (at least from what I've read).
I deleted all yarn references and changed it to pnpm, ran pnpm import, deleted node_modules, and ran pnpm install.
When I try to build one project that uses react and vite, I always get "Rollup failed to resolve import".
For example, I have zustand and then it says it failed to resolve import use-sync-external-store/shim/with-selector.js.
tanstack/react-query asked for @tanstack/query-core and @tanstack/query-persist-client-core.
I tried adding them to the external rollup property in the vite.config file, but I have added 59 different packages so far.
Whenever I run, it says it's missing a peer dependency, I add this dependency in the external, run build again, and it complains about another dependency, I add it to external, build again, and then I keep in this dependency hell.
I don't know how to fix it.
I have this in my .pnpm
link-workspace-packages=true

and this in my pnpm-workspace.yaml
packages:
  - 'apps/*'
  - 'shared/*'

This is my complete vite.config.mts file
export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => ({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    svgr(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    preserveSymlinks: true,
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    },
  },
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      external: [
        'clsx',
        'use-sync-external-store/with-selector.js',
        '@floating-ui/react-dom-interactions',
        'htm/react',
        '@tanstack/query-core',
        '@tanstack/query-persist-client-core',
        'react-router',
        '@remix-run/router',
        'immer',
        '@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/classCallCheck',
        '@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/createClass',
        '@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/objectWithoutPropertiesLoose',
        'reselect',
        'redux-thunk',
        'react-merge-refs',
        '@tanstack/query-devtools',
        'html-parse-stringify',
        '@progress/kendo-charts',
        '@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/extends',
        '@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/inheritsLoose',
        '@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/toConsumableArray',
        '@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/assertThisInitialized',
        'dom-helpers/addClass',
        'dom-helpers/removeClass',
        '@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/inherits',
        '@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/possibleConstructorReturn',
        '@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/getPrototypeOf',
        '@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/defineProperty',
        'invariant',
        '@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/slicedToArray',
        'substyle',
        '@progress/kendo-draggable-common',
        'pdfjs-dist',
        'make-event-props',
        'make-cancellable-promise',
        'tiny-invariant',
        'warning',
        'dequal',
        'merge-refs',
        'use-sync-external-store/shim/with-selector.js',
        'tslib',
        '@progress/pako-esm',
        'js-cookie',
        'nano-css',
        'nano-css/addon/cssom',
        'nano-css/addon/vcssom',
        'nano-css/addon/vcssom/cssToTree',
        'copy-to-clipboard',
        'screenfull',
        'set-harmonic-interval',
        'throttle-debounce',
        'react-universal-interface',
        'fast-shallow-equal',
        'ts-easing',
        '@xobotyi/scrollbar-width',
        'fast-deep-equal/react',
        '@kurkle/color',
        '@zxing/library',
        '@progress/jszip-esm',
      ],
    },
  },
  esbuild: {
    drop: ['console', 'debugger'],
  },
  define: {
    APP_VERSION: JSON.stringify(process.env.npm_package_version),
  },
}));

Taking zustand as an example it is only installed in the app/app1 folder (I'm using app1 for anonymity)
This is my root package.json
{
  "name": "monorepo",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "pnpm install && turbo build",
    // removed for simplicity
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "husky": "^9.0.11",
    "prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "turbo": "^2.0.11",
    "typescript": "^5.5.2"
  },
  "packageManager": "pnpm@9.7.1",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=20"
  }
}


and this is my app1 package.json (I kept only some relevant packages that I think makes sense)
{
  "name": "app1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^5.40.1",
    "@tanstack/react-query-devtools": "^5.40.1",
    "@tanstack/react-query-persist-client": "^5.49.2",
    "idb-keyval": "^6.2.1",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.23.1",
    "zustand": "^4.5.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build --outDir build",
    "preview": "vite preview --outDir build --port=3000",
    "test": "vitest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.14.7",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "typescript": "^5.5.2",
    "vite": "^5.4.1",
    "vitest": "^1.6.0",
    "webpack": "^5.90.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "axios": "axios/dist/node/axios.cjs"
    }
  },
  "overrides": {
    "redux-persist": {
      "redux": "^5.0.0"
    },
    "redux-state-sync": {
      "redux": "^5.0.0"
    }
  }
}



Lets take zustand as an example. What package.json is this declared in? The workspace root, sub packages, possibly both? Secondly. what subpackages import zustand. Are they the same ones that declare it in the sub package.json?

Also please share the whole rollup config. The plugins etc matter a lot as well as other config options around symlinks, commonjs, and resolution plugins/config. As it looks like you are using babel, probably gonna need that config too.

@adsy, thank you for offering to help me. I've updated my question with some relevant information. Thank you.

Adding this to the .npmrc solved my problem:
shamefully-hoist=true

I think it is because I must use preserveSymlinks: true due to the Jenkins environment we use to build.
I found it because in the documentation it says the node-linker should be set to hoisted when:

If you are running Node.js with the --preserve-symlinks flag.
node-linker


Yep! That would be it. Preserve symlinks would not be viable with PNPM's default structure. Though its worth noting, by "shamefully hoisting", you opts of PNPMs ability to prevent bad practices (see https://medium.com/pnpm/pnpms-strictness-helps-to-avoid-silly-bugs-9a15fb306308https://medium.com/pnpm/pnpms-strictness-helps-to-avoid-silly-bugs-9a15fb306308) for what I mean.
